# Family of subsets of $n$-element set s. t. union of each four subsets has cardinality at most $n-2$ has size at most $2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

> Let $n>1$, $X$ be a set of cardinality $n$ and $A_1,\ldots, A_k$ be a sequence of distinct subsets of $X$ such that $|A_i\cup A_j \cup A_l \cup A_f|<n-1$ for all $1\leq i, j, l, f\leq k$. Show that $k\leq 2^{n-2}$.

I tried many techniques to solve that problem, in particular I solved some simple cases, observed that the proof is straightforward if there exists an element which is in at least $2^{n-3}-1$ of sets $A_i$ or if there exist three of them such that their union has cardinality exactly $n-2$, but I don't know if this is helpful when considering the general case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is bothering me in your question is the word "sequence". Say, the statement is false for $k=2^{n-2}+1$ and $A_1 = \dots = A_k = \varnothing$. So, maybe, there should be "set" instead of "sequence"? Or there should be the word "distinct" before "subsets"?

Comment: You are right, they should be distinct. I will edit the question.

Comment: For a given $A_i$, if $\alpha$ is a subset of $A_i$ not in the sequence, we can replace a sequence member with $\alpha$ to get a new sequence satisfying the conditions.  Have you tried shifting or replacement arguments?  I wonder if the sets in the sequence can be "shifted" into the initial segment of a squashed ordering.  The result would sort of follow by pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Is this from a book? It might help to know which/what chapter this is supposed to be from. Either way, the relevant keyword to search is "r-wise t-union" families (or "r-wise t-intersecting" for the complements).